# Spring Data Rest - validate Bean before save

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, bean-validation

I've been searching for the simplest and best way to validate my entities before they are created/updated and after much googling, I couldn't find a clean/modern one.

Ideally, I would have loved to be able to use @Valid as follows:

```
import javax.validation.Valid;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.HandleBeforeCreate;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.HandleBeforeSave;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryEventHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

@Slf4j
@Validated
@Component
@RepositoryEventHandler
public class CustomerEventHandler {

  // Triggered for POST
  @HandleBeforeCreate
  public void onBeforeCreate(@Valid Customer entity) {
    log.info("Saving new entity {}", entity);
  }

  // Triggered for PUT / PATCH
  @HandleBeforeSave
  public void onBeforeSave(@Valid Customer entity) {
    log.info("Saving new entity {}", entity);
  }

}
```

The Customer entity being:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {
  @NotBlank
  private String firstname;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

What's the modern, easy way to validate entities in Spring Data REST?

Note: I'm using Spring Boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your pom.xml in linked GitHub project. You have just a dependency to validation annotations, but the proper way with Spring Boot is to use the spring-boot-starter-validation Dependency. The Spring Boot Starter Dependencies add the "magic" to your project, which triggers automatically the validation based on your annotations.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I my German blog I have written an article about this topic:
https://agile-coding.blogspot.com/2020/11/validation-with-spring.html

Comment: Good catch ;) Now I see in the logs the validation is working, although rather than returning the error message to the client the app is simply crashing with a ConstraintViolationException.
Thank you Elmar!

Answer (score 0):

I want to suggest a few best practise that every developer, who starting as junior/beginner should be know. Don't put any Validation annotation in Entities, using them in DTO/Resource classes. and the best way to practise validation is that you can handler `MethodArgumentNotValidation` exception in your own Spring Boot of Exception Handler class annotated that class `@RestControllerAdvice` and create your own `@interface` annotation instead of using more validation annotation.

Comment: I agree, that's what I normally do (validating the DTOs) with Spring Data JPA.
With Spring Data REST you don't have DTOs, you have projections to be returned to the client but they can't be used to receive requests as well.
Also, I'm trying to make it good enough for a production environment and at the same time writing as little code as possible (I believe that's the power of Spring Data REST)